# How do I parse non-integer octals in Java?

Tags: java, octal

This may not be possible, but I figured it can't hurt to ask.
I have a program that needs to convert non-integer decimals into octal notation. From what I can tell, Java can only handle integer octals automatically. I've cobbled together something of a kludge, which involves breaking down the number into powers of eight, something like this.

.abcd = x * (1/8) + y * (1/64) + z * (1/512) + ......

which would be displayed as "0.xyz", if that makes any sense. The problem is, this is resulting in a lot of rounding/truncation errors for long numbers. Is there a better way to do this?

(edit)
Here's the algorithm I've been using to process the digits to the right of the decimal point:

```
double floatPartNum = Double.parseDouble("0." + temps[1]);
     if (floatPartNum > 0) {
        int p = 1;
        result = result + ".";
        while (floatPartNum > 0 && p < 16) {
           double scale = 1/(Math.pow(8, p));
           int modT = (int)( floatPartNum / scale );
           result = result + modT;
           double modScale = (double)modT * scale;
           floatPartNum -= modScale;
           p++;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know of no floating point or fixed point support for octal numbers in base Java. If you show your algorithm for extracting the octal digits from the decimal, maybe we could help reduce the error.

Comment: Here's the algorithm I'm using. The part to the left of the point is handled as if it were an integer, so I'm only including the part dealing with the numbers to the right of the point:

Comment: Oops, I forgot pressing return posted things...
`         double floatPartNum = Double.parseDouble("0." + temps[1]);
         if (floatPartNum > 0) {
            int p = 1;
            result = result + ".";
            while (floatPartNum > 0 && p < 16) {
               double scale = 1/(Math.pow(8, p));
               int modT = (int)( floatPartNum / scale );
               result = result + modT;
               double modScale = (double)modT * scale;
               floatPartNum -= modScale;
               p++;
            }
         }
`

Answer (score 1):

There are some methods in the Float and Double classes that allow you to get the bit-wise representation of the number; for example [`Double.doubleToLongBits(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits%28double%29).

You could then extract the mantissa and exponent parts from the double-as-bits, and convert them to your octal format with no loss of precision.

---

However, it might be simpler to just fix your current algorithm.  I'd have thought that you *should* be able to implement your approach without loss of precision.  (Have you considered the possibility that the precision has already been lost; i.e. in the processes / calculations that produced your numbers in the first place?)

Answer (score 1):

Your `p < 16` is artificially truncating your output. When I try your code on `1.0/3.0`, I get `0.252525252525252`, but there's actually enough precision in the double to add three more octal digits, yielding `0.252525252525252525`, if you change that to `p < 20`. But if you're concerned about "long numbers", then you might find that `double` just isn't big enough for your needs.

By the way, your loop can be simplified significantly, to:

```
for(int p = 1; floatPartNum > 0 && p < 20; ++p)
{
    floatPartNum *= 8.0;
    result = result + (int)floatPartNum;
    floatPartNum -= (int)floatPartNum;
}
```

(tested), which eliminates all the need for `Math.pow` and so on. (`Math.pow` works by performing logarithms and exponentiations; it's overkill, and potentially roundoff-prone, when you're just multiplying by eight.)

Answer (score 0):

How about something more like this?:

```
  String result = "";
  double floatPartNum = temps[1];
  if( floatPartNum > 0 )
  {
     int p = 1;
     result = result + ".";
     while( floatPartNum > 0 && p < 16 )
     {
        floatPartNum *= 8.0D;
        int modT = (int)floatPartNum;
        floatPartNum -= modT;
        result = result + modT;

        p++;
     }
  }
```

Much fewer operations to introduce errors. (I am sorry I can't test this code before posting it, I am not near my programming tools.)